# Bluemix AlchemyLanguage api TextGetRankedNamedEntities text limit?

Tags: ibm-cloud, alchemyapi

The alchemy api for entities (TextGetRankedNamedEntities) seems to have a text limit around 7500 characters.  I was wondering if this was a documented limitation or a defect?

Answer (score 1):

I just successfully sent a text doc with >40,000 characters successfully without any issues. I've posted the **API Notes**, **CURL Command**, and **Response** I got below.

**CURL Command:**

```
curl -X POST \
-d "apikey=$API_KEY" \
-d "outputMode=json" \
--data-urlencode text@testing.txt \
"https://gateway-a.watsonplatform.net/calls/text/TextGetRankedNamedEntities"
```

**Response:**

```
{
    "status": "OK",
    "usage": "By accessing AlchemyAPI or using information generated by AlchemyAPI, you are agreeing
to be bound by the AlchemyAPI Terms of Use: http://www.alchemyapi.com/company/terms.html",
    "url": "",
    "language": "english",
    "entities": [
        {
            "type": "Company",
            "relevance": "0.833922",
            "count": "31",
            "text": "TextGetRankedNamedEntities"
        },
        {
            "type": "Quantity",
            "relevance": "0.833922",
            "count": "31",
            "text": "50 kilobytes"
        }
    ]
}
```

### API Notes:

1. Calls to TextGetRankedNamedEntities should be made using HTTP POST.
2. HTTP POST calls should include the Content-Type header: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
3. **Posted text documents can be a maximum of 50 kilobytes. Larger documents will result in a "content-exceeds-size-limit" error response.**
4. Language detection is performed on the retrieved document before attempting named entity extraction. A minimum of 15 characters of text must exist within the requested HTTP document to perform language detection.
5. Documents containing less than 15 characters of text are assumed to be English-language content.
6. Disambiguation of detected entities is enabled by default. Disambiguation information will be included for each entity that is successfully resolved.
7. Entity extraction is currently supported for all languages listed on the language support page. Other non-supported language submissions will be rejected and an error response returned.
8. Enabling entity-level sentiment analysis results in one additional transaction utilized against your daily API limit. Entity-level sentiment analysis is currently provided for both English and German-language content.
9. Disambiguation and quotations extraction are currently available for English-language content only. Support for other languages is in development.

Comment: Thanks that worked.  I was originally using GET and received a 414 URI too long error.  I switched over to using post but couldn't get it to work until I added the application/x-www-form-urlencoded header.